# Is there any way to specify the player.js version on playing vimeo?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

When I access any videos on Vimeo, https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871 for example, it responds `player.js`. It is https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/3.22.9/js/player.js(`Player - v3.22.9 - 2020-10-14`) at the moment. Because the version has some issues around playing on a tablet I have, I'm looking for some ways to force to use the other version.

Is there any way to specify the other version with a url parameter(such as https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?player_version=3.22.8) or some other ways?

**[Updated]**
Note: the issue occurs are following.

The tablets we(and our customers) have are below:

- Android 5.1.1; d-02H Build/HUAWEIM2-802LD
- Chrome 43.0.2357.93

It fail to play any videos on vimeo on the tablet. I connected the tablet to Mac and found out that the following errors are occurring. I'm not sure since when the issue has been occurring but it surely worked on the former versions.

```
TypeError: e[(e.length - 1)].toJSON is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.a.onload (https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/3.22.9/js/player.ja-JP.js:10:69648)
    at XMLHttpRequest.nrWrapper (https://vimeo.com/467141591:98:23894)
```

**[Updated:2]**
Two weeks after my inquiry, I've received an answer from Vimeo that they only support Android 6 or higher. Though I've never received any responses by email in the end, I could get a response from https://twitter.com/VimeoStaff

Although I wrote the version when I made my first inquiry, after two weeks of waiting, the answer was to increase the version of Android. They were very generous in their support system.

Comment: doubtful. you should contact vimeo for support.

Comment: Yes, I've contracted Pro plans and asked them but they haven't answered yet, written on their support page that due to tons of queries are sent because of COVOD-19.

Comment: What issues are you having?  If your plan supports it, you could always stream to your own player via HLS.

Comment: As the videos are restricted to embed, I couldn't stream them with the other players in order not to be able to freely download.